# how to generate a new variable by one column's value overriding the other's in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that is essential in the following format:

| group | var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | . | . |
| a | 1 | . | . |
| a | 1 | 2 | . |
| a | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| a | 1 | . | . |
| b | 1 | . | . |
| b | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| b | 1 | 2 | . |
| b | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| b | 1 | 2 | . |

I want to generate a new variable that in this format:

| group | var1 | var2 | var3 | new var |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | . | . | 1 |
| a | 1 | . | . | 1 |
| a | 1 | 2 | . | 2 |
| a | 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| a | 1 | . | . | 3 |
| b | 1 | . | . | 1 |
| b | 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| b | 1 | 2 | . | 3 |
| b | 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| b | 1 | 2 | . | 3 |

Help pls?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `pmax` and `cummax` (assuming the `.` are missing -`NA`).  Grouped by 'group', `invoke` `pmax` `across` the columns that 'starts_with' 'var' in column names, and get the cumulative max (`cummax`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(newvar = cummax(invoke(pmax, 
        c(across(starts_with('var')), na.rm = TRUE)))) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   group  var1  var2  var3 newvar
   <chr> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
 1 a         1    NA    NA      1
 2 a         1    NA    NA      1
 3 a         1     2    NA      2
 4 a         1     2     3      3
 5 a         1    NA    NA      3
 6 b         1    NA    NA      1
 7 b         1     2     3      3
 8 b         1     2    NA      3
 9 b         1     2     3      3
10 b         1     2    NA      3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(group = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b"), var1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    var2 = c(NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), var3 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you out

```
lastValue <- function(x)   tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1)

df$newvar <- apply(df, 1, lastValue)
```